# Functions whose second derivative is of the same sign

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

$$\frac{\mathrm{d^{2}} }{\mathrm{d} x^{2}}\psi=\frac{2m}{\hbar^{2}}\left [ V\left ( x \right ) -E\right ]\psi$$

I must show that $E>V\left(x\right)$ for all $x$ for every normalisable solution to the time-independent Schrödinger equation.

Let's suppose $\psi$ is a function of $x$, and if $\psi(x)>0$ then $\psi''(x)>0$. Similarly, if $\psi(x)<0$ then $\psi''(x)<0$.
A positive derivative indicates an increasing rate of change (convex up and local minima exists) and a negative derivative indicates a decreasing rate of change(concave down and local maxima exists) but why isn't the function able to start and end at $x=0$?

Comment: Starting and ending at $0$ would mean that the second derivative is nonpositive (concave down) at some points, contradicting $\psi''>0$.

Comment: What does "start and end at x=0" mean?

Comment: Hang on. I'll edit the question to give it a bit of context

Comment: Your question is a bit cryptic. "for all x for every normalisable solution to the time-independent Schrödinger equation." I assume the expectation value in this state is intended. This result follows straightforwardly by taking the inner produci with ψ and noting that ${d^2}/d{x^2}$ is a non-positive operator.

Comment: what is the criterion for normalizability? Should $\psi$ be square integrable or you are also considering $\delta$ function normalization?

Comment: You should use the constraint of normalizability.

Comment: @vnd. In quantum mechanics, normalizable means square integrable.

Comment: @Tom-Tom In such a case, for $V(x) = 0$ everywhere, and positive energy $E$, the SE has plain wave solutions not normalizable via square integrability criterion.

Comment: @vnd. Good remark. Planes waves are indeed not normalizable, which means that they have no physical meaning. They would actually contain an infinite energy !

Comment: @Tom-Tom A plain-wave solution does indeed have a physical interpretation. If $E=\frac{p^2}{2m}$ where $p$ is the momentum, then a plain-wave solution simply represents the free motion of a particle with momentum $p$ and energy $E$ (Since both the energy and momentum are simultaneously measurable here). However, the condition $E > V(x)$ everywhere stated in the problem,  admits plain-wave solutions which are not normalizable using square integrability.

Comment: @vnd. You are right except for one thing: plane waves represent the free motion of **infinitely many** particles with momentum $p$ and energy $E$.

Comment: yes, so in such a case, we usually normalize the wave function so as to represent a probability current density corresponding to unit particle flux.

Answer (score 2):

It is not required that $E> V(x)$ for all $x$; only that $E > V(x)$ for *some* $x$.

**Proposition:** If $\psi$ is a normalizable (i.e., square-integrable) solution for the time-independent Schrödinger equation, then $E > V_{\text{min}}$.

*Proof:* If not, then $V(x) - E$ is positive for all $x$, hence the time-independent Schrödinger equation written in the problem implies $\psi$ and $\psi''$ have the same sign everywhere. Let $g = \psi^2$. Then $$g''(x) = \frac{d^2}{dx^2} \psi(x)^2 = 2(\psi'(x)^2 + \psi(x) \psi''(x)) > 0$$ for all $x$. This implies $g'(x)$ is increasing everywhere, so $$\int_{b}^{N} g(x) \, dx = \int_{b}^{N} \int_{a}^{x} g'(y) \, dy + g(a) \, dx = \int_{b}^{N} \int_{a}^{x} g'(y) \, dy \, dx + (N-b) g(a) $$ $$ \ge \int_{b}^{N} \int_{a}^{x} g'(a) \, dy \, dx + (N-b) g(a) = g'(a) \int_{b}^{N} (x-a) \, dx + (N-b) g(a) = g'(a) \left( \frac{N^2 - b^2}{2} - a(N-b) \right) + (N-b) g(a)$$ for all $a\le b$. If we choose some $a$ such that $g'(a) > 0$, then taking $b>a$ and $N \to \infty$ shows $\psi$ is not normalizable. Such an $a$ must exist since otherwise $g$ is everywhere monotonic (and no monotonic function is $L^1$-integrable). $\blacksquare$

Comment: E>V_min classically means that kinetic energy is never negative.